# Error on deleting vector file written by QgsVectorFileWriter on Windows

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, vector-tiles, windows

I wrote a QGIS plugin which writes vector layers to vector files using PyQGIS method [QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3). I then use different processing methods to clean geometries, etc. and finally write the output as *mbtiles* file. Till here everything fine.

But when I try to clean up the vector files (Geopackages) `os.remove` throws an exception on Windows (but not on Linux):

```
[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

The code I'm using looks something like that:

```
# write vector file
file1 = os.path.join(path, 'out_1.gpkg')
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer, file1, QgsProject.instance().transformContext(), options)

# 2. clean geometries
inn = {
    "INPUT": file1,
    "OUTPUT": QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
}
proc1 = processing.run("native:fixgeometries", inn)

# 3. fix right to left
file2 = file1.replace('_1.gpkg', '_2.gpkg')
inn = {
    "INPUT": proc1['OUTPUT'],
    "OUTPUT": file2,
}
processing.run("native:forcerhr", inn)

# 4. remove obsolete file
os.remove(file1)
```

I see different threads about file lock problems on Windows, but can't figure out how to finally delete these files. It seems that QGIS blocks these files till the plugin stops running, at least I can delete them manually once the process stops.